# Could someone explain how to fix the 'listings.sty' issue in a very "for dummies" way?

Tags: listings, installing

I've been trying to use the `listings` package, but whenever I try to install it I get the message:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `listings.sty' not found.
```

I'm new to LaTeX and I have no clue how to do anything. I'm using TexStudio.

Could someone walk me through how to fix this. I've seen many threads about the very same issue, but I simply don't understand what I have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MiKTeX](http://www.miktex.org) is capable of installing missing package on-the-fly through it's `texify` executable. However, manual installation is best done through the [MiKTeX Package Manager](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html):

> ### Working With the Package Manager
>
> You use MiKTeX Package Manager (MPM) to install and remove packages.
>
> The package manager can be run in two modes: batch and windowed.
>
> MPM runs in batch mode if you specify command-line options such as `--install` and `--update` (see [`mpm`](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/mpm.html) for a list of available command-line options).
>
> To start the package manager in windowed mode, click Start → Programs → MiKTeX 2.9 → Browse Packages). You will see a window similar to this:
>
> [image]
>
> ### Installing Packages
>
> You install packages as follows:
>
> 1. Select all wanted packages in the list view.
> 2. Click on + to install the packages.
>
> For example: you want to install the ConTeXt package:
>
> 1. Locate and select the ConTeXt package in the list view, e.g., type the key sequence <kbd>C</kbd> <kbd>O</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>.
> 2. You can now click + to install the package.